# Hybrid thin films containing azobenzene with reversible photoresponsive behavior

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, photochemistry

I am going to prepare hybrid thin films containing [azobenzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azobenzene) with reversible photoresponsive behavior. I have read about different combinations of inorganic layers such as [layered double hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_double_hydroxides) (LDH) with azobenzene molecules.

However, I can't understand the photocatalytic role of the inorganic portion in the isomerization of azobenzene. Can insulators be used as the inorganic part instead of semiconductors (if I consider LDH as the doped composite)?